# reading json from file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json file:

`test.json`:

```
{"rows" : [
  {"key": "value"},
  {"key": "value"}
 ]
}
```

I tried this code to read it:

```
var json = require('test.json');
for (var row in json.rows) {
    console.log(row.key);
}
```

it prints:

```
/usr/local/bin/node json-parser.js
undefined
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `row` is the variable holding property name not the object, so you need to retrieve it using the property name ( Refer : [`for...in` loop documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)). In your case it will be the index of array. There is no need to use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterator here, a simple for loop is enough.

```
for (var row in json.rows) {
  console.log(json.rows[row].key);
}
```

```js
var json = {
  "rows": [{
    "key": "value"
  }, {
    "key": "value"
  }]
};

for (var row in json.rows) {
  console.log(json.rows[row].key);
}
```

---

With a simple for loop

```
for (var i=0;i < json.rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(json.rows[i].key);
}
```

```js
var json = {
  "rows": [{
    "key": "value"
  }, {
    "key": "value"
  }]
};

for (var i = 0; i < json.rows.length; i++) {
  console.log(json.rows[i].key);
}
```

---

Since the property holds an array use`Array#forEach` method to iterate.

```
json.rows.forEach(function(v){
  console.log(v.key);
}
```

```js
var json = {
  "rows": [{
    "key": "value"
  }, {
    "key": "value"
  }]
};

json.rows.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v.key);
})
```

Comment: why would `json` variable has a property named `row`? shoun't the `json var` which I read have property named `rows` and each `var row` has a property named `key`? (according to json structure `test.json`)

Comment: @Jas : refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @PranavCBalan yes I understand that the `for loop` iterates the `properties` I don't get why each `json` variable should even have a property named `row`! shouldn't `json` var read represent the `json.test` it has no property named `row`

Comment: the first `for` prints nothing and the second way (Object.keys) does yield `value` and then `value`